# Google visualisation API - Multiple charts based on Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am pretty new to Google Visualisation Charts API. I am trying to display different charts based on dropdown selection. Chart is not getting displayed if I am adding another draw function. Please find my fiddle below I have tried.

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/PFa5h/5/

JS Code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var selectedVal = "";
   $('#dashboard-chart-type').change(function(){
     selectedVal = $(this).val();
     alert(selectedVal);
     switch(selectedVal) {

      case "average":
          $('#visualization').empty();
          init();
          break;
      case "total_install":
          debugger;
          $('#visualization').empty();
          init();
          break;
      case "total_uninstall":
          debugger;
          $('#visualization').empty();
          init();
          break;
      default:
          $('#visualization').empty();
          init();
          break;
  }
});

if(selectedVal==""){
    init();
}

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Long struggle made the multiple charts work based on selection. Problem was to load multiple charts you need to call the draw visualisation function through call backs. I found this useful info from google groups.

Then I added some functions `init()`,`init2()`...etc to load different charts . One thing here we need to note is to call `drawvisualisation()` inside `init()` method, It should be called only using **google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization());** rather calling **google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);** as mentioned in the google playground examples.

```
 function init(){
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization());
 }
 function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria', 'Denmark', 'Greece'],
    ['2003',  1336060,    400361,    1001582,   997974],
    ['2004',  1538156,    366849,    1119450,   941795],
    ['2005',  1576579,    440514,    993360,    930593],
    ['2006',  1600652,    434552,    1004163,   897127],
    ['2007',  1968113,    393032,    979198,    1080887],
    ['2008',  1901067,    517206,    916965,    1056036]
]);

// Create and draw the visualization.
new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data,
    {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
        width:600, height:400,
        vAxis: {title: "Year"},
        hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
);
}
```

Call was not happening when I tried to use the code **google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization)** which was spoiling my graph by not displaying.

Here is my fiddle which works based on selection.
http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/PFa5h/6/

Here In the above fiddle I made to load different types of charts like Line,Column, Stacked etc...